# How to store multiple userids in same model?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm fairly new to Django and attempting to store a model which will hold transaction information for a purchase between 2 users; a buyer and seller. I therefore want to store 2 UserIDs:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    transactionid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # USERID OF SELLER
    # USER ID OF BUYER
    orderid = models.ForeignKey('Order', db_column='orderid', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=PAYMENT_STATUS, default='pending', max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to use the following foreign key:

```
seller = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

however, to my understanding, this will only store the current logged in user which means I wouldn't be able to set both? Is there a better way to do this rather than modifying the model twice (esentially from both accounts)?

Any reccomendations or advice appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope, in the `Transaction` model you are going to add the entry if someone made any purchase. Buyer Id you can get from the current user. Seller ID yo can get from the product information.

For adding more than 1 foreign key with the same Model, you can use the related_name parameter.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    transactionid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='seller_name')
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buyer_name')
```